# how to destroy jssor image slider object?

Tags: jssor

I want to change slider images on click of different tabs. all the tabs contain different number of images. so i want to destroy the old object and load new images in a new object. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The [nested slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html) demonstrates a parent slider works with 3 child sliders.

Not sure if it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks but i solved my problem by destroying old and recreating the slider every time tabs are changed.